# how do those webdriver option arguments work?

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

```
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-automation'])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
  "source": """
    Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {
      get: () => undefined
    })
  """
})
```

I have learned web scraping for a while.
To get access to lots of pages, I frequently use the code above to prevent my driver be detected. I put a lot of effort trying to realize how these codes work background, but still clueless.
I'm wondering if there is any scraping expert can explain how the web detects a bot, and how the codes help us evade detection.

Comment: there is no blog on them as such, you will have to go through the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript fingerprinting and context analysis is often used by websites to tell whether connecting client is a human or a robot.

Since website can execute arbitrary javascript on your web browser instance it can look for small details that are only present in automated browser instances and flag you as a robot.

For example, your line:

```
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
  "source": """
    Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {
      get: () => undefined
    })
  """
})
```

Adds a script to execute on each new page (browser tab) initiation that removes `navigator.webdriver` javascript property which is added by Selenium.

You can actually check this by launching a Selenium browser and opening up developer console and typing in `navigator.webdriver` to see what's the value (where's in your personal browser the value is always undefined):
[image]

Selenium also adds some browser option flags automatically that you override in your code by explicitly telling it to reverse these:

```py
# Selenium sets this True by default but we can reverse it:
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
```

Browser fingerprinting is very complex and is a bit too much to cover in a single stackoverflow question. For more, see a lengthy blog post I wrote on this subject [How to Avoid Web Scraping Blocking: Javascript](https://scrapfly.io/blog/how-to-avoid-web-scraping-blocking-javascript/)

Comment: Thanks for sharing all this information with me. I cannot imagine how long it would take to get all that knowledge myself. Your answer really helps me a lot.